# Validating a dynamically populated table content in PHP

Tags: php

Can some one help me on this as I'm really going nuts!

I've got following;

`.........Some code and then`,

```
      <?php

        if(isset($_POST['sendone']))
        {   if(!isset($_POST['delz']))
            {echo 'No check boxes are selected!'; return;} else 
            {
            $mohan = "<table border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1' id='brQndTab' class='brndTa'>";
            foreach($_POST['delz'] as $delz)
                        {
                            $delz=mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$delz);
                            $QR = "SELECT bname, bvariant, bsku FROM brands WHERE id='$delz'";
                            $rr = mysqli_query($db,$QR) or die ("SQL Error");
                            $roV = mysqli_num_rows($rr);
                            $rr = $rr->fetch_assoc();

                            $mohan .= "<tr class='sc_eght' ><td class='sc_five'>".$rr['bname']." ".$rr['bvariant']." ".$rr['bsku'];
                            $mohan .="</td>
                               <td><textarea  style='width:80px;' name='schema[]' id='vtext' class='sc_one' rows='1' cols='1' maxlength='100'></textarea></td>
                               <td><input  style='width:80px;' type='text' name='allocas[]' id='vtext' class='sc_two' size='80' maxlength='5'></td>
                               <td><input  style='width:80px;' type='text' name='channelz[]' id='vtext' class='sc_three' size='120' maxlength='30'></td>
                               <td><input  style='width:80px;' type='text' name='provinz[]' id='vtext' class='sc_four' size='120' maxlength='30'></td>
                               </tr>";

                        }
                            $mohan .= "<form method='post' action=''><input type='submit' name='sendMe' id='sendMe' value='Save'></form></table>";
                            $_SESSION['cb'] = $mohan; }

                            if(isset($_SESSION['cb'])) 
                            echo $_SESSION['cb']; 
        }   

        if(isset($_POST['sendMe'])) 
        {       
            if($_POST['provinz'] == '')
            {echo $_SESSION['cb']; echo "Province is empty!"; return;} else { echo $_SESSION['cb']; echo "Saved!"; return;}

            if($_POST['allocas'] == '')
            {echo $_SESSION['cb']; echo "Allocation is empty!"; return;} else   { echo $_SESSION['cb']; echo "Saved!"; return;}

        }

        ?>
```

..........

The problem is when `sendMe` is submitted;

1. Gives me and error `Notice: Undefined index: provinz in C:\xampp\htdocs\docs\add_invoice\testmm.php on line 104`
2. Even though I try to get the values of the dynamic table textboxes via `if(isset($_POST['sendMe']))` doesnt appear to be a right method of doing that. Any suggestions would be great.

Can some one help me on this two things? In case if my problem is not clear please comment so I shall do my best to dilute the ambiguity.  Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could try to open form above in script (at the very start of mohan variable)? Currently, your form just hold submit button?

Comment: It looks to me like you're adding the <form> tag to `$mohan` after you've added the input fields. You can do `var_dump($_POST)` below `if(isset($_POST['sendMe']))` to see which fields are submitted to your post. Likely these values aren't posted because they're not part of the form you submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Basically `$_POST['sendMe']` is set but `$_POST['provinz']` is not set or defined by PHP, you need to check its set before using the comparison operator `==` on the value:

***You can do it like:***

`if(!isset($_POST['provinz']) || $_POST['provinz'] == '')`

**Or simply use `empty()`**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['sendMe'])){
    $error = array();

    // provinz
    if(!empty($_POST['provinz'])){
        $provinz = $_POST['provinz'];
    }else{
        $error['provinz'] = $_SESSION['cb']." Province is empty!";
    }

    // allocas
    if(!empty($_POST['allocas'])){
        $allocas = $_POST['allocas'];
    }else{
        $error['allocas'] = $_SESSION['cb']." Allocation is empty!";
    }

    // finally process the variables if no error
    if(empty($error)){
        //do something with
        $provinz;
        $allocas;
        echo "Saved!";
    }
}
?>
```

Then to show the errors somewhere you will have an array of errors that match your key:

`<?php echo isset($error['allocas']) ? $error['allocas'] : null ?>`

Comment: Irrespective whether the provinz or allocas textbox has a text or not it echos 'Saved'. So it doesn't really validate. How can I correct this? Thanks

Comment: Updated with an example. Do your php first then echo.